# Automator to change PSD to JPG

Tags: automator

I need a batch conversion tool to change PSD to JPG image files.

I have not seen a simple Automator action for this.

Comment: You said, "_I have not seen a simple Automator action for this._" but have you tried creating one?  It is doable.  Did you see **Change Type of Images** under **Photos** in **Automator**?

Answer (score 1):

if you use Photoshop this is easy to do, under File/Automate/Batch which will allow you to pick files, set any options on quality etc that you like